# How can I set the MTU for just one remote server in Linux?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, mtu

Hi I have a linux server that is behind a customer firewall. I can SSH into it but when I try to scp, the connection dies. I believe this is an MTU issue as described here: http://www.snailbook.com/faq/mtu-mismatch.auto.html. How can I set the MTU to a smaller value for just this one customer? I don't have these issues with our other remote servers so I think the problem is at the customer end. I've tried talking to the customers IT guy about this and he didn't seem to know what an MTU was.

My remote server is running Fedora 10

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems a perfectly legitimate question to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MTU is based on the interface not ip-adresses. You can setup a second (virtual) interface with a different ip and the mtu you want.

Comment: You can't change the mtu of a virtual interface separately from the phyiscal one

Answer (score 0):

Remember that this problem maybe caused by the missed configure MTU on the network equipment between you and your server. What file size you are trying to transfer?

Answer (score 0):

11 years and no answer on how to do it. @quanta's answer was correct that it's a misconfiguration somewhere else.

You CAN set an MTU on a single route.

`ip ro add $DEST via $GW mtu NNN`
where:

- $GW is your normal network gateway
- $DEST is the destination IP
- NNN is the MTU you want.

e.g. `ip ro add 8.8.8.8 via 10.0.0.1 mtu 576` to set the smallest possible MTU. May cause other problems, but it will cause your system to send only small packets outbound to the destination.